# How do I validate $_GET to allow only specific key

Tags: php, get

Let's say my current URL is

```
http://domain.com/category/cars/?page=2
```

How do I validate on this page to allow only `$_GET['page']`?

If user type on URL something below, will go to error page.

```
http://domain.com/category/cars/?page=2&bar=foo
http://domain.com/category/cars/?foo=bar&page=2
http://domain.com/category/cars/?foo=bar&bar=foo
```

Let me know..

Comment: Why do you care what else they add to the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
if( count($_GET) > 1 || !isset($_GET['page'])) { /*error*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should care only of GET/POST variables used in your application. Validate and escape them accordingly, check if they're set. The rest should be ignored - you don't need to care of them and display errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $allowedKeys = array('page');


    $_GET = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip($allowedKeys));
```

You won't have to worry about your undesired parameters and values, as they will not be accepted via the `$_GET` method. With the above code, the only allowed `$_GET` parameters is 'page'

Answer (score 0):

I might do this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET)
  {
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$value)
      {
        if($key!='page')
          {
            $error=true;
          }
      }
  }
?>
```